# Reledmac - interline (line spacing)

Tags: line-spacing, reledmac

A simple question. Is there any way to change the interline of a Reledmac text (namely, between a `\pstart` and a `\pend`) without messing the algorithm of page-breaking?

I tried to move up the 11.5 from my

`\fontsize{10}{11.5}\selectfont`

but it ends up in a total mess, even with a small shift.

The `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}` has no effect, too.

Reading the manual, maybe (perhaps!) that this behaviour has something to to with this:

> \add@penalties is the last macro used by \do@line. It adds up the
> club, widow, and interline penalties, and puts a single penalty of the
> appropriate size back into the para- graph; these penalties get
> removed by the \vsplit operation. \displaywidowpenalty and
> \brokenpenalty are not restored, since we have no easy way to find out
> where we should insert them.

So, what could I do to get a bit of space between the lines without messing the *mise-en-page*?

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.

There wasn't any issue about that. I just had a (well hidden, indeed) \interlinepenalty=10000 right before the bibliography and then **before** my ledmac code. It was this that was driving eledmac crazy.

Sorry for the question :)

Comment: Please accept your answer as an answer. This way does not appear to be open.